# Don't know how to install wireless card?

Tags: wireless

Installed Ubuntu on my IBM Think Pad which was running winxp. It came with an Airlink101 wireless card for laptops (AWLC3028)because the built in wi-fi on the computer never worked. How do I get it working on Ubuntu. I am a new Linux user and need step by step instructions, please help me

Answer (score 0):

Hardwire the computer into your network with an ethernet cable so you have internet access, then verify the internet connection is working properly by going to Facebook or something.  In the top right corner of the screen click the Shutdown icon and click "System Settings".  Once that opens, click the "Software and Updates" icon.  Once that opens, you'll see a tab on the far right labeled "Additional Drivers"; click it.  It may take a few minutes, but if it can find a driver for your card, it should appear in this window and let you "activate" or "apply" it.  Do so, then reboot the computer.  If you have an AMD or NVIDIA graphics card, it may also show you drivers for that as well.  Generally speaking when selecting drivers, I pick the ones labeled "proprietary", or the ones with a little red ribbon on them.  Proprietary drivers are issued by the hardware manufacturer, and the little red ribbon means it has been tested pretty thoroughly.